# Index on Select fields when they use a condition?

Tags: mysql, indexing

From my understanding, as a rule of thumb I should make an index on the fields in the `Where` Clause of my selects:

`Select CustomerName from Orders Where CustomerID=10`

I'd want an index on CustomerID but would not need one on `CustomerName1`. I know it is more complex than this but as a starting point for this question at least :)

My question is if I add a condition to the/a `Select` field does that in essence now become a `Where` clause necessitating an Index?

`Select If(CustomerSalution is NULL,CustomerName,concat(CustomerSalutation,' ',CustomerName)) as CustomerName from Orders Where CustomerID=10`

Comment: It might, it depends on how the query planner decides to do the query. Don't forget that only one index can be used at a time, so you might need a multi-column index to optimize both the `WHERE` and `IF`.

Comment: You should have indexes that reflect the query patterns of your application. If you only ever need to look up customers by `CustomerID`, then you wouldn't need an index on name. However, if it is possible that you would want to look up a customer by name then `CustomerName` should have an index. Keep in mind that only one index can be used at a time

Comment: The answer is either "No" - which is too short for SO. Or it would be too long, because one would need to list all situations when an index can be used, thus showing that it won't be in your case.

Answer (score 0):

See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql for a brief discussion on how to write optimal indexes for common situations.

For your cases:

```
Select CustomerName from Orders Where CustomerID=10
INDEX(CustomerID)   -- good
INDEX(CustomerID, CustomerName)  -- better; but in this order
```

For

```
SELECT IF(... ((multiple columns mentioned)) ..)
    from Orders
    Where CustomerID=10
```

can use either of the indexes mentioned above.

"necessitating an Index" -- Nothing, except performance, "requires" an index.  Without any indexes, your `SELECTs` will simply scan the entire table, checking each row.  For 100 rows, you might not notice.  For 1 million rows, you would "need" an index.